# How to execute a scroll mechanism when user clicks right/left clickable image using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a page where I want users to be able to scroll right/left by pressing an right/left image arrow. But im not sure how to connect the clickable images to the overflow-x mechanism of the html to scroll right/left.

CSS contain all images where users can scroll

```
.imgScroll{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
white-space:nowrap
}

.arrows{(clickable arrows, to scroll right/left)
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.5;
top: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

PHP where all images are set to the scroll box

```
(while loop execute do the following)
$childImg .= "<img src='../ProductImages/ChildImages/$childName' 
class='imgBotSize' onclick='openNav()'>";
```

HTML

```
<div id="botWrapper">
     <?php echo "<p1>" . $pDetails . "</p1>"?>
     <div id="imgBot">
         <div id="imgBoxBot">
             <div class="arrows" style="right: 180px">
                 <img src="../arrow-right.png" width="70px" height="70px">
              </div>
              <div class="arrows" style="left: 180px">
              <img src="../arrow-left.png" width="70px" height="70px">
               </div>
               <div class="imgScroll">
                    <?php echo $childImg;?>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's a nice image carousel here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: this is really good thanks

Comment: yeah, it's a well-worded question because it was clear that you were trying to create a carousel :)

Comment: just realised you asked for vanilla JavaScript and that carousel uses jQuery. Was there a specific reason you were avoiding jQuery?

Comment: I just like knowing why things are working, Im new to web development so i want to know as much as I can, with jquery you kinda just copying a code that someone has done without really knowing why that is working, but im tired of working on this Im going with this hahaa. unless you know any examples on pure javascript

Comment: ok I see. You can do a lot more with jQuery than JavaScript and it is less long-winded to write. I just wrote a big function in JavaScript because the jQuery library wasn't available, and it was SO tedious :(  https://gist.github.com/vogelbeere/073bddfc8f3d09b568990e69de37c807

Comment: Wow thats alot of functions lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149600/discussion-between-yvonne-aburrow-and-luke-ds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create an image carousel.

There's a nice image carousel here: [kenwheeler.github.io/slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and you can set different options for how you want it displayed.